# How to animate a mask with interval steps and not consecutive flow animation

Tags: animation, modifiers, masking

I'm animating a mask using the screw modifier and Boolean. but as the mask starts to reveal the LED lights, because its a consecutive flow animation, it's revealing bit by bit the LEDs, rather than one full LED at a time. How can I make the LEDs animate one at a time as the goes around revealing the LEDs.

https://streamable.com/1hwbei

[image]

Comment: you could choose another method like an array around an offset and you just increase the count?

Comment: That worked well, only one thing from making it what I'm after, I cant set the array to 0, Its always 1. So one LED is always visible:  https://ibb.co/vQH1XjV

Comment: Several answers here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194078/radial-wipe-using-mask-modifier/194101#194101 . Or using the array consider making it invisible when needed.

Comment: you can make the object invisible at the beginning (for example keyframe its visibility in the Outliner)

Comment: I was this article on BSE, but I'm getting a message it cant be animated, is this what you are referring to? https://ibb.co/Gx6G366

Comment: You can't animate the eye icon, but you can animate the screen icon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At last, a use for the *Build* modifier?

Create a fan-filled circle-mask with the same number of segments as you have LEDs, rotate in Z to the desired start-point. Give it a *Build* modifier, set to the appropriate frame start/end, and 'Reverse'.

[image]

Segments are made visible one at a time.

@blender breath Thanks for the comment.. 'mask' is a bit vague - it could be so many things..

- For a 3D mask, as you have done, assign a *Solidify* modifier to the circle, to get a cylinder disappearing in chunks, which can be used in a *Boolean* to cut away the LEDs
- 2D, a perfectly black *Diffuse BSDF* mask in a black world,
- Or, as here, 2D, a *Holdout* mask through to transparent film, composited against a coloured background -

or, I'm sure, many other possibilities, for use in compositing, or as a texture.

[image]

Comment: That worked well. For a minute I was confused when you mentioned "mask" I was selecting the circle triangle fan and then the LEDs and doing a Boolean (Ctrl + minus on the number pad) thinking that would be the masking method, but the result was awkward  . Then occurred Ill try adding the solidify modifier to the Build modifier and got the same results as your animation. Is this the same way you did yours? https://streamable.com/falxid

Comment: @blenderbreath  Oops, that wasn't very clear, was it? Thanks. See Edit.

Comment: Heaps better now, Cheers!